# Adjective describing a person who has lots of children, not "fertile"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a single adjective that means "this person has lots of children"?

Context: I'm not actually talking about a person. I'm talking about a data structure in a computer program, where objects are organized in a hierarchical tree and each object can have few or many "child" objects.  So "fertile", and similar words, are inappropriate. The object doesn't produce children on its own; the programmer must assign children to the object.

Comment: @japreiss Given that such words are generally created to describe living creatures, and that living creatures generally don't have "the presence of many children" without simultaneously having "the ability to have many children", I think you may be looking for a word that doesn't exist.

Comment: You might see if there's an appropriate term from the adoption / foster community.

Comment: It's also possible that the veterinary community might have a term for people with lots of pets that could fit your need.

Comment: This is a classic [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/276803). Your real question is "How should I describe this data-structure?" but, instead of asking about that, you're asking about the details of a particular solution attempt.

Comment: Please don't post answers in comments.

Answer (score 74):

Merriam-Webster [gives](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolific) **prolific**:

> 1 : producing young or fruit especially freely :  fruitful

The source is [Latin *proles*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prolific) meaning "offspring".

Comment: Oh jeez. Really? I forgot the actual word itself?

Answer (score 51):

**fecund**:

> producing or able to produce many babies, young animals, or plants
>   - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fecund)

Comment: Nice answer, I think I learned that word for the GRE :) But *fecund* and *prolific* both connote the *ability* to produce lots of children. I need something that connotes the presence of many children without the fertility implication.

Comment: Edited question to provide context

Comment: Note that fecund can mean either the ability to produce, or the state of having produced (although it does generally mean both).  In my read, however, fertile is more related to the potential to produce, whereas fecund tilts towards the actual production.

Comment: @japreiss: While that's true of *fecund*, it's not true of *prolific*; something is *prolific* only if it really has produced lots of children.  So for instance a "prolific author" is someone who has written lots of books, not someone who could easily write lots of books.

Comment: I was going to say fecund as well. However, @japreiss is right that it connotes the ability to reproduce, not reproducing itself. However, the word *prolific* implies that the production – in this case of children – has already happened. It has a similar connotation to *fruitful*.

Answer (score 25):

Your question seems not to be about a general family situation but about the technical situation with data structures in computer science. In the latter case, a *binary* tree is for internal nodes with two children, *ternary* for three. The generalization is then

> **multiary**

for many children. Other, similar ways of saying this are _n- ary (for an arbitrary number not necessarily many) or *var-ary* for a possibly changing number of children. All of these are somewhat ... let's say non-classical, but are acceptable within the technical community.

Comment: +1 for focusing on the OP's context.  [Polyadic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyadic) would also work.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to distinguish between binary/ternary/multiary, rather to distinguish between different nodes in a single multiary tree ([Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)).  Some nodes have many children; others have few.

Comment: In other words, I'm looking to replace the phrase "nodes with many children". Which is already fine, but I enjoy using a bit of colorful vocabulary when appropriate.

Comment: @jpreiss: The whole tree is called k-ary (for different values of k) if all nodes  have k children or fewer. You can also use the term for individual nodes: "This node is binary but this one is ternary but this other one is multiary". However if you're at the point where you're specifying for a particular node, you most likely know already how many nodes it has exactly _or_ you want to compare and you'd say "This node _has more children_ than this one."

Comment: @japreiss Consider your readers above your desire to use "colorful vocabulary." It's much more important that someone reading your writing can follow it easily. Throwing in nonstandard terminology is more likely to confuse than help; I'd advise against it.

Answer (score 22):

Given what OP has described in the comments, I think **branching node** would be ideal.  We're referring to a node which has branches.  We could modify it to **highly branching node** to clarify we're specifically talking about nodes with *a lot of* branches.

Comment: maybe branchiferous? :D

Comment: this is my favorite so far because it functions like a single word. I mainly want to avoid the clunky "node with ____" or "node of ____" construct.

Comment: If the context is heavily focused on the tree structure, the "branching" may be unnecessary without the "highly" modifier. That said, this is the best answer here for a technical context; clear and straightforward.

Answer (score 19):

Might not be quite correct but as a fellow programmer I would say

**Abundant**

> Richly supplied; wealthy; possessing in great quantity. - From [Wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abundant)

Comment: +1 from me.  An *abundant* node in a tree contrasts well with a *sparse* node, or even a *childless* node.

Comment: Programmer here. Good choice.

Comment: @joe "This node is abundant. This node is sparse." Good call

Answer (score 13):

In medicine, the adjective *multiparous* is used to describe a woman who has had more than one child.  It is also used in biology to describe species that normally give birth to multiple offspring at once (like a litter of puppies).

Answer (score 12):

A tree is a special kind of [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29), so I'd go with the standard terminology for a graph, which is saying that your node has a **high** (or large) **degree**. You lose the *parent/child* metaphor, but I think your readers will understand you better.

Comment: As the OP is refering to graph theory, I think that this is the best answer so far. The degree of a vertex (node) is the number of edges (links) incident to such vertex, so if your graph is a tree, the degree of your node would be the number of children + 1 (except for the root node). +1

Answer (score 11):

Given that the structure you're trying to describe is a data *tree,* it would make sense to use a tree metaphor.  You might try [Burgeoning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/burgeoning)

**burgeoning**

> begin[ning] to grow, as a bud; put[ting] forth buds, shoots, etc., as a plant

Because the tree is specifically a *data* tree,  [Polyadic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyadic) would also work.

**polyad**

> A group consisting of an indeterminate number of things or people.

---

Other tree-related terms are verdurous, flourishing, sprouting, germinating, and pullulating.

Comment: +1, like both the natural language sound of this and the relevance to a data structure rather than a reproductive animal

Answer (score 6):

I'd say:

**dense**

My reasoning is that a tree where each node has one child is a [degenerate tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_%28graph_theory%29), from there I see that such a tree is "sparse". You're looking for the opposite of that, and an antonym of sparse is dense. Also there's some technical [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph) of "dense" to back that up.

Comment: *Sparse*/*dense* is terminology that I would personally apply to the whole graph, not to a vertex.

Comment: Hmmm...good point. I was going to say "dense subtree", but then that might not be true either (one vertex may have many children, but then those children may have sparse subtrees, at which point the parent vertex's subtree is sparse).

Answer (score 5):

***Philoprogenitive*** is the word.

> Having many offspring. [[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/philoprogenitive)

---

Another option is ***multi-child*** and it is suitable for your context as well. Here is an example usage:

> The optimal algorithm is suitable for the cases when the given DFG has a small number of multi-parent and **multi-child nodes**.
>
> <sub>*Real-Time Embedded Systems: Optimization, Synthesis, and Networking*
> By Meikang Qiu, Jiayin Li</sub>

It can also be used in parenting context:

> Lalumière et al. (1996) argue that, in accordance with a Darwinian view, within **multi-child families**, siblings compete for the same resource: parental investment.
>
> <sub>*Oxford Handbook of Evolutionary Psychology* By Louise Barrett</sub>

*Note:* *Multi-child* might mean just more than one child too but there are also terms like *two-child, three-child* etc.

Comment: Bingo X 2, imo.

Comment: typical programming scenarios reflect simple *placement* of a node within a tree.  maybe it's just me, but philoprogenitive seems more to indicate that the nodes themselves produce children.

Comment: @erich: This is the only word that actually covers "having". Even the OP said "not fertile" but most up-voted answers are direct synonyms of it. People might be just up-voting what they know without paying attention to the details. I also mentioned another word.

Comment: i would agree on "having" when it is understood in the *containing* sense. multi child is the correct term; i will +1 if you remove the first word.

Comment: I was just thinking "progenitory", but I guess "philoprogenitive" has an established definition.

Comment: Nice word @ermanen !. This is a very good answer, +1. However, I would say that the OP is refering to graph theory and (in my opinion) in this specific context FedericoPoloni's answer fits better.

Answer (score 3):

I would profer **populous**.

> full of residents or inhabitants, as a region; heavily populated.

1. Unlike *prolific* or *fecund*, it doesn't imply that the populous object *created* the descendant entities. Instead, it *has* many. (As @Joe brought up in the comments on the OP, foster/adopted families can have many children, which is another situation where the family is populous, but the parents were not prolific and may specifically not be fecund).
2. Populous has the same roots as *populate*, a common computer term.

---

As an alternative to go with the tree/branching terminology often used, there is **fruitful**.

> abounding in fruit, as trees or other plants; bearing fruit abundantly

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use **rich** and to introduce it's usage in your text by means of a definition e.g.: `Definition (rich): A node with at least 3 children is called *rich*.`

While I can't find a single-word in english denoting "having (possessing) many children" there is a german word for it: `kinderreich`. This literally translates to `rich in children`. According to [Merriam](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/prolific) `rich` is a synonym of `prolific` (suggested by @Matt Gutting).

Note that I assume that *rich*

- can be rigorously defined on your graph.
- is unambigous i.e. no other meanings of *rich* are possible in its context.

Comment: Rich means something else in programming contexts, sorry.

Comment: @Joshua The only meaning of rich specific to programming I could find is rich-client which should be rather hard to mistake a node attribute in a graph for. Unless you had other usages/meanings in mind I don't really see the problem?

Comment: Rich text - formatted text; Rich data structure - means something more complex than a tree ; Rich node - not currently used but easily confused with Rich data structure.

Comment: @Joshua While I still don't think that confusion could arise as easily here as you seem to think I edited my answer to include that line of thought.

Answer (score 2):

For hierarchical data structures I use

**Bushy** to indicate dense connections to child data.

as opposed to

**Gangly** to indicate sparse connections to child data.

Comment: I like it, but "bushy" sounds like it describes the whole structure, not a single node.

Comment: @japriess Good point. I use these words to describe both entire trees, and individual nodes. But I agree that the primary affinity is toward the entire tree.

Answer (score 2):

### There isn't one.

In the **technical context** of the OP's *full* question there is no accepted single word technical term.

Many of the words mentioned are great for general responses, especially in terms of the question title, but would be questionable usage in a more specific technical context.

If this is referring to a tree graph structure specifically, it might be indicated by referring to the node in question being capable of having a `branch factor` of two or higher (slightly awkward, as branch factor is more commonly used to describe a currently existing node or tree, not its potential), or having unlimited branching.

In terms of object descriptions, we might refer to it as having multiple properties (children are properties of the parent object when they are directly part of its structure and not simply referred to by some other structure that is a property, such as a list).

In describing data structure relationships (such as in a relational database), this would be called a `One-to-Many` relationship in terms of the parent object to its children (possibly the closest to a single term, as it is standardized as a compound hyphenation).

"Multiple child objects" are properly described… just as that. Due to the nature of programming, it's far more important to properly describe the relationships as precisely as possible than it is to unnecessarily force brevity in a way that may be confusing or fail to actually be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You could always coin something. The Greek word *polyteknos* ([πολύτεκνος](https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%84%CE%B5%CE%BA%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82)) describes someone who is the parent of three or more children. Nobody will actually understand what you mean unless you define it, but there is a long tradition of importing Greek words into English. You will be in good company.

Answer (score 0):

Using the notion of “assigned” mentioned in your question, maybe “[over-assigned](https://www.housing.siu.edu/residence-halls/room/overassigned)”/”[under-assigned](https://www.nmu.edu/housing/node/256)” (like University dorm rooms sometimes are) would work since you're talking about things and not people.

If “over/under” are too judgmental, maybe you could hyphenate “heavily-assigned” and “sparsely-assigned” and even throw in “unassigned” on the other extreme.

(“Overburdened,” “heavily-burdened,” “lightly-burdened,” “under-burdened,” and “unburdened” might capture a bit better the “parent” angle, but only for those who sometimes see their children as burdens!)

Answer (score 0):

With respect of the context being a data structure, just about any term is going to confuse - as a programmer for many years, I've never had a conversation with anyone or seen any written reference where a 'fertile' concept has been applied to a data structure. The structure itself is not 'fertile' - it has capabilities to have zero or more siblings and so it is not in any way fertile. In the human being context a human in general is not fertile, but a particular woman may be by way of her physiology and behaviour.

As a programmer I find the notion quite bizarre. We create data structures to handle applicable cases and generally anything with siblings is a structure that caters for ranges such as 0..n, 1..n, etc. There's no notion of fertility.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the term:

***multibrancher***

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00371-005-0280-8
Subdivision method to create furcating **object with multibranches**

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for **highly ramified** or **greatly ramified**.

To **ramify** is to branch out, or to cause branches to form. It is used in mathematics and philosophy as well as botany.

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). This is an interesting answer IMO, but it would be an even better one if it included references (to a dictionary definition, or example of usage in this context)

Answer (score 0):

I might say "highly paternal" or "highly maternal".

Each of those has cultural meaning, unfortunately ("paternal" makes me think of paternalism, and "maternal" makes me think of nurturing).

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Some references to a dictionary definition or evidence of usage would be desired. Otherwise the post seems opinion-based and is more appropriate for a comment (when you achieve enough reputation to leave one)

Comment: Yes, my answer is definitely opinion-based.  Is that inappropriate for this question?

Comment: It is generally not desirable on ELU. However, references such as evidence of usage in written language (e.g. examples from Google Books) would improve the answer substantially. Look for more tips [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is there a single adjective that means "this person has lots of children"?
>
> Context: I'm not actually talking about a person. I'm talking about a data >structure in a computer program, where objects are organized in a >hierarchical tree and each object can have few or many "child" objects. So >"fertile", and similar words, are inappropriate. The object doesn't >produce children on its own; the programmer must assign children to the >object.

You switched from person to object with children.
An object with children that doesn't produce children as a parent is a nursery or kindergarten.

Answer (score -3):

How come **descendants** hasn't come up? All of the "children" have **ancestors** therefore the **ancestors** have many **descendants** whether or not they are actually **offspring**.

Comment: Because *descendants* can't be used adjectivally to describe a person.

Comment: Seriously? so you're not a descendant of your parents?

Comment: That's not what I said. *descendant* is a noun, not an adjective. Even an adjectival form like *descendantal* wouldn't mean that someone has a lot of descendents, it would mean that someone was a descendent!